# How to use data from the broadcast receiver, before the activity is shown, in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I'm using receiver in order to know if the phone got internet connection.

I'm using this code:

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    private Boolean netOk = false;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        ConnectionChangeReceiver1 netReceiver =  new ConnectionChangeReceiver1();
        IntentFilter filterNet = new IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
        getActivity().registerReceiver(netReceiver, filterNet);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(netOk){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"U GOT NET" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"U DON'T GOT NET" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    public class ConnectionChangeReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null
                    && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

            if (isConnected){
                netOk= true;
            }else{
                netOk= false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, that the netOk, stays on false.
Now I understand that only after - `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume` - only after than the receiver class is being called.

So the question is: if I want to know before the activity is shown to the user if there's a internet connection or not, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to get the response synchronously.

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // test for connection
    if (cm != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected() 
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So if im getting it right the Receiver option is not so good for my purpose?

Comment: @4this I changed my answer

Comment: i've copied the code - and it shows me the word - context - as a mistake. Now im putting the code,as u can see, in a Fragment - so i've tried to add or change it to -getActivity() - but it dosen't give me that option - any idea what should i do?

Comment: @4this in fragment context is your activity, replace it with getActivity()

Comment: well i've chnge it - but it was an error on the getActivity() - but when i've erased the static from the function line - it shows that all good - is it a big thing to delete the static word? and also thank you for your help

Comment: You should declare your method as static and use Application context, rather than adding this method everywhere, and passing getActivity(). Avoid passing activity context wherever it can be replaced by application context. It was showing error because you cannot use non-static members in static environments. Create a separate Utils.java class and add all static methods there, and access them as Utils.method(), this way you can use them anywhere. Always add (or try to) lifecycle related code in Activity and Fragments.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection() {
    Context context = Application.BASE_CONTEXT;
    try {
        if (context != null) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            // test for connection
            if (cm != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For getting context anywhere:

Create an SampleApplication.java file, like this:

```
 public class SampleApplication extends Application {
```

public static Context BASE_CONTEXT;

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    BASE_CONTEXT = getApplicationContext();
}
```

}

In AndroidManifest.xml file, add the following attribute to  tag

```
<application
    android:name="<your package>.SampleApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    >
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: First of all thank you for the reply - i copied the cod but but the - BASE_CONTEXT - is shown me as an error - is it because i'm in Fragment ? and if not what i need to change?

Comment: Its just a placeholder, it means use your application context here, make a static context instance by extending Application class, so that you can use context methods anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This can be the first thing you can check inside onCreate method. Or you can check this inside some activity which starts this Activity, or may be Splash, if this is first activity.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your exact requirement, Like what are the things that you want to perform with this Logic. So i can guide you the right solution to achieve this task.

See in android there are many possible ways to achieve different requirements,

These are few of the possible ways that you can achieve this,

1) For every android Application alomost there will be a Splash Screen coming before starting the Main Activity, So in that case you can check whether your internet connection was active or not , Upon checking you can store boolean values like True on Success and Flase on Failure in **Persistent Store** or in some **Application static Variable** .

2) And if you want to check the user Network Connection in the background, You can start a **service** from the **BroadcastReveiver** and you can monitor it for every 10 to 15 mins, And you can save the same to your persistent store and you can use it in your Activity.

3) So by storing the result in your Persistent Store will help you to use the same in your whole application.